# How to pass a XML node to mongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb-java

I've just started exploring MongoDB and I would like to understand how to pass a xml node (say repeating node) to MongoDB.

So far I've tried these:

I'm able to convert XML to JSON
I'm able to write key, value pairs into a collection in MongoDB (static data/hardcoded data)

I'd like to understand how to pass a json string consisting of multiple key value pairs of the equivalent xml structure into MongoDB?

so far I've been tried to insert data using below methods available via Mongo JAVA API

document.put("name", "Test Data");
document.put("CreatedDate", new Date ());

I'd like to apply this to a whole json string...

In other words, I would like "name", "Test Data" , etc fields to be dynamically picked up from the JSON string's key/value pair

```
{"employees":[
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

the Java code should be able to scan the json and insert into MongoDB.

```
document.put("firstName", "John");
document.put("firstName", "Anna");
```

so on

Any pointers to this is appreciated

PS: am NO expert on JSON arrays, etc

Thanks
Raghav

Answer (score 0):

There is a com.mongodb.util.JSON class that has a parse(String) method that will parse your JSON string and turn it into a DBObject you can then insert into MongoDB. e.g.,

```
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;

// ...

DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(
    "{\"employees\":[" +
        "{\"firstName\":\"John\", \"lastName\":\"Doe\"}," +
        "{\"firstName\":\"Anna\", \"lastName\":\"Smith\"}," +
        "{\"firstName\":\"Peter\", \"lastName\":\"Jones\"}" +
     "]}");
```

Comment: Thanks, will explore !